# Can I connect a ground rod to a wire on my backyard

Tags: electrical, grounding

Long story short, my mom's kitchen got a renovation, the house had no ground (old house), the electrician punt the colored wires correctly including a ground that I asked him to, but now that they are finishing I was inspecting and it turns out he did not put the ground rod, just the green cable and because is concrete, it's expensive to fix.

One of the green wires is hanging outside in a junction box and I'm a 100% sure is part of the renovation.

So, my question is, can I use this green cable and put the rod for the ground there  To get the green wires connected? it's an area with just grass, it's a 10 gauge wire,  And get the ground travel through that wire

[image]

Comment: Pictures and general location will be nice.  Most places now require two ground rods about 8 feet apart.  The wire from the panel to the rods should be a single non spliced wire, but if it needs splicing, the splices must be non removable.  So no wire nuts/wagos.  There is also ground that uses the rebar in the cement slab/foundation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, pictures of the main panel or the wire outside in the backyard? The backyard is like 10 meters / around 32 feet from the main panel

Comment: Picture of the junction box outside at least.  It is a wire covered with green insulation and not a cable(with multiple wires in it).  Ground must be a bare wire or a single wire with green covering.

Comment: @crip659 Image added

Comment: Those wires are for a different circuit, so no.  You should have a thicker single ground wire attached to the panel going to ground rods.

Comment: Well, thanks for the comment @crip659 I thought so. Thanks again

Comment: Your location on the planet might help us understand what electrical codes you're supposed to conform to.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate mexico, which basically mean USA code, but it's no the same and certify electricians here are like unicorns. That's why I'm trying to learn for my self by asking over the web to experience people. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your main electrical panel should be grounded with a ground rod, so if the wire is part of the *panel* ground at the main panel, it can be grounded.

However, if the wire you are talking about is not at the main panel, but part of the ground wire for a separate circuit, it would not be appropriate to bond to a grounding rod.

If your home has an underground cold water main, that might be an alternative method (or in addition) to running a ground rod.

Comment: The only rod connected to the main panel is the one for the neutral (old house)

Comment: @Emir   Neutral and ground is bonded together at the main panel.  It is the only point/place where they are allowed to be bonded/attached together.  So if you have a wire from the neutral bus to a ground rod, you are good.

Comment: I've seen that, neutral and ground bonded, but two wires goes to the main, green and white... In this case, there is only a white one (neutral) + the 2 hot lines

Comment: @Emir  If there is no green line in the panel, then where does the green line in the picture go?  You might find it useful to post a picture of the open panel (i.e. so that the wires are visible) either in this question or another question.

Comment: @mdfst13 The panel is a new main, the electrician was supposed to fix everything including the fact that there is no ground rod for the old one. The green wires goes to a main panel bus bar, but that bus bar is not connected to any ground rod, it's just a circuit without ground. That's why Im looking for a way to fix this

Comment: @Emir please [Edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/296809/edit) your question and add a pic of your panel.